# Wordpress upload video convert MP4 format

Tags: php, wordpress, video, ffmpeg

**Create custom video convert plugin - MP4 format**

> Bellow upload code work fine but how to convert MP4 format after
>   insert media library.

```
    media_handle_upload('upload_video_file', 0)       

    exec("ffmpeg -i $fullsize_path -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f mp4 -s 320x240 $value");   

   <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type='file' id='upload_video_file' name='upload_video_file'></input>
      <?php submit_button('Upload') ?>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ffmpeg to convert video,first make sure its installed properly on your server and running.
Check ffmpeg installed or not on your server.

```
$ffmpeg = shell_exec('which ffmpeg')); 
$ffmpeg = shell_exec('type -P ffmpeg');
```

If `$ffmpeg` return empty then it means its not installed on your server, if its return absolute path it means installed on your server.

Then you can execute `exec` commond Just like below

```
exec("ffmpeg -i {input}.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 {output}.mp4");
```

`-vcodec` parameter to specify the encoding format to be used for the output video.

`-acodec` codec (input/output)
Set the audio codec. This is an alias for `-codec:a`

For more commond check ffmpeg link https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: Hi sir , this code work in php folder but word press  plugin folder only execute upload file conversion without file upload successfully,

Comment: You can use this code after file upload on server whether in plugin or any other place.

Comment: @BalanK just try to find out, where `move_uploaded_files` is working, after that you need to convert your newly uploaded video.